# Prevent lxml from escaping ampersand in `&#x0d;` when writing to file

Tags: python, xml, escaping, lxml

I need to add an attribute to an existing XML element. This attribute must contain the `&` character inside an entity like `&#x0d;`. When writing the modified XML to a file the `&` becomes `&amp;` and thus destroys the enttity.

```py
import lxml.etree as et

e = et.Element("a")
e.set("attribute", "first line&#x0d;&#x0a;second line&#x0d;&#x0a;")
t = et.ElementTree(e)
t.write("test.xml")

# expected result
<a attribute="first line&#x0d;&#x0a;second line&#x0d;&#x0a;"/>

# actual result
<a attribute="first line&amp;#x0d;&amp;#x0a;second line&amp;#x0d;&amp;#x0a;"/>
```

How can I prevent lxml from escaping the `&` character when writing the XML to a file? I need the string `&#x0d;&#x0a;` to appear unescaped in the final XML file. Another application reading this modified XML file depends on the string `&#x0d;&#x0a;` appearing unmodified.

Comment: Could you add some more context why this is necessary? As far as I know, the expected result is not XML anymore - any XML parser you send it to should reject it.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was suspecting. I actually need to create an attribute in the form of `Content-Length=6439518&#x0d;&#x0a;Content-Type=image/jpeg&#x0d;&#x0a;`. I do not know why exactly this is necessary. The program that should read in this modified XML file seems to expect this format.

Comment: Either you want the output to be XML, or you want the ampersand to be unescaped. You can't have both.

Comment: But isn't `&#x0d;&#x0a;` an escaped value for LF/CR already? Why does lxml escape an ampersand in a special character like `&#x0d;`? I need this string to be written out as is. I will update the question with this example.

Comment: PyCharm, for example, does accept the entity `&#x0d;` inside an attribute and doesnot mark it as an error. So I guess should be able to use it, as it is valid XML.